# apt-get fails on i386/debian docker image

Tags: docker, apt

I have a 32-bit Ubuntu server, running 17.10 Artful & with `docker.io` installed (my understanding is this is the only version available for 32-bit)

```
jonny@grizzly ~ $ lsb_release -cs
artful
jonny@grizzly ~ $ apt list | grep docker.io

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

4384:docker.io/artful,now 1.13.1-0ubuntu6 i386 [installed]
```

I am attempting to use `i386/debian` image (I have also tried `32bit/Ubuntu` with similar results), and having issues with `apt-get`. Sources appear to be configured sensibly, but `apt-get update` gets 404 errors. Hitting the same URLs (with `.gz` appended) from browser works fine. `ping` works within Docker image, `wget` & `curl` aren't available so haven't been able to further diagnose possible network issues.

```
jonny@grizzly ~ $ docker run -it i386/debian /bin/bash
root@1023ad95222c:/# more /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
root@1023ad95222c:/# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
  404   [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
  404   [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
  404   [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404   [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-i386/Packages  404   [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404   [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried various different mirrors I've found online with no difference. I've also tried a few different versions/tags of the `i386/debian` docker image. No proxy used to access internet on this server. Are there any other steps I may be missing here?

Comment: Did you get any solutions??

Comment: @keshav no I don't think so, I stopped using that server shortly after asking and switched to another with a 64bit processor